# Is there an English translation of "Sarvartha Siddhi" by Vedanta Desika?

Tags: vaishnavism, vedanta, translation-request, resource

I'm looking for an English translation of "Sarvartha Siddhi" by Vedanta Desika. In fact I'm only interested in one part of it, "I.69", in which a reference to Yadavaprakasa and his theory of time is made. But if there's a translation of the whole work, that would be great. I've been looking for it for weeks but found nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for- https://archive.org/details/Sarvarthasiddhi/page/n4

Comment: @Shashwat No, this seems to be a text from another author. The Sarvartha Siddhi that I'm looking for is a commentary on "Tattva Mukta Kalapa" by Vedanta Desika. This is the original text in Sanskrit: https://archive.org/details/TattvaMuktaKalapaMRamaSastri1900 . But thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely that you would find an English translation of the Sarvartha Siddhi. The Tattvamuktakalapa is considered one of the tougher texts. Most traditional scholars in Visistadvaita themselves haven't studied it deeply. A tamil translation by Kaniambakkam Devanathachariar is appearing as a serial in the Tamil magazine "Sri Nrisimha Priya".

Answer (score 1):

here is the link for sarvarta siddhi (the commentary of tattva mukta kalapa by vedanta desika).

https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/SarvArtha-Siddhi-of-Sri-Vedanta-Desika-Dr-V-N-Seshadri-Acharya-1993-OCR.pdf

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at:  [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Have an enriching Journey ahead.